# Where to install a water conditioner?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, pump, water-softener

I want to install a water conditioner for the purpose of minimizing the sticking of minerals to the faucets and a shower glass. From what I read a catalytic water conditioner will do the job. I will be installing one of [these](http://www.stuart-turner.co.uk/products/stuart/stuart-water-conditioner/).

I will be installed at a 5 story building. This is a European concrete block building with a flat roof. My apartment is on the 4th story and the water service installation is as follows:

- City mains meter at ground level connects to a water tank on the roof of the building. This is a storage water tank and not a pressure tank.
- Storage tank is connected to this [pump](http://www.stuart-turner.co.uk/products/stuart/stuart-ph-es/35-es-fl/) which is also located on the roof of the building.
- The pump is connected to the apartment on the 4th story providing adequate pressure.

It seems water flow is an important factor when choosing the water conditioner. I want to measure the water flow but I am getting  different results depending on where I measure. Where in line should I be installing the water conditioner?

1. **At ground level or on the roof of the building before the storage water tank.** I`m sure the water flow would fluctuate quite a bit here, also would minerals build up in the storage water tank? thus defeating the purpose? or once the water is conditioned minerals would not build up in the tank? The tank does get a quite a bit of heath from direct sunlight in the hotter months.
2. **After the water storage tank but before the pump.**
   This option seems to be the most logical to me as the conditioner will possibly extend the life of the water pump and the conditioned water will not be sitting in the tank.
3. **After the water pump installed at the roof of the building.**
   At this point there will be higher and constant pressure. I am not sure how important that is for the effectivity of the water conditioner.
4. **After the water pump at apartment level on the 4th story.** This is also an option, not sure if it makes any difference from option 3, possibly reduced pressure.

Also a follow up question, if installing after the water pump is it safe to use the pump maximum flow for selecting the water conditioner of should water flow be measured anyways?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reconsider reliance on unproven technology (magnetic water conditioning). There is a ["lack of peer-reviewed laboratory data, mechanistic explanations, and documented field studies to support its effectiveness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_water_treatment#cite_note-1)

and ["an internal study in 1996 at Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory found no difference in preferred crystal structure of scale deposited in magnetic water treatment systems"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_water_treatment#cite_note-Krauter1996-9), disproving hypotheses of proponents of the technology.

Comment: you seem to be referencing to magnetic conditioning. This post is about a catalytic water conditioner, I believe they are different. I do realize the hardness of the water is not affected, I only want to prevent minerals from sticking to objects as stated in the opening statement of the OP. I need a maintenance free solution, I'm sure the catalytic conditioner will not make minerals stick more so it's worth a try since it`s a one time install, even if the difference is negligible.